# Refactoring a Stepper component in Stencil.js to use Component properties when stepping through views

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, stenciljs

I am completely new to Stencil.js and working on a Component that should navigate the user through different steps of a Carsearch. The existing step methods for stepping through the different steps should be refactored. The Component should take properties and pass them to each step; however, I am kind of lost on how to do that, after googling for hours for similar components in Stencil.js. Therefore, I would appreciate any useful help or hints on how to do that.

The code is the following, I added some comments to clearify what needs to be done:

```
import {Component, Event, EventEmitter, h, Method, Prop, State} from '@stencil/core';
import {Icon} from '../../utils/utils';
import {xxxCarsearchResultModel} from './xxx-carsearch-result.model';

@Component({
    tag: 'xxx-carsearch',
    styleUrl: 'xxx-carsearch.scss',
    shadow: true
})
export class CarSearch {
    /**
     * The score
     */
    @Prop({mutable: true, reflectToAttr: true}) tsn: string = null;
    @Prop({mutable: true, reflectToAttr: true}) hsn: number = null;
```

I added the following properties to the component

```
  @Prop({mutable: true, reflectToAttr: true}) key: string;
    @Prop({mutable: true, reflectToAttr: true}) header: string;
    @Prop({mutable: true, reflectToAttr: true}) listTitle: string;
    @Prop({mutable: true, reflectToAttr: true}) favoritesTitle: string;
    @Prop({mutable: true, reflectToAttr: true}) hasSearch: boolean;
    @Prop({mutable: true, reflectToAttr: true}) searchPlaceholder: string;

    @Event() carSelected: EventEmitter<VhvCarsearchResultModel>;
```

The component state should change when stepping through the component

```
  @State() page = 1;
    @State() wsresult: [];

    brand: string;
    model: string;
    fuel: string;
    type: string;
    power: string;
    variant: string;
    selectedcar: string;
    parsed: string;
    audi: string;
    bmw: string;
    volkswagen: string;
    mercedes: string;

     apiPath = 'https://test.xxx.de/tarifrechner/api/v1/car/guided';


    @Method()
    async getTsn() {
        return this.tsn;
    }

    @Method()
    async checkLogo(response) {
        for (var key in response) {
            // skip loop if the property is from prototype
            if (!response.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue
            var obj = response[key];
            for (var prop in obj) {
                // skip loop if the property is from prototype
                if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
                // iterating through the nested objects
                console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
            }
            this.parsed = (obj[prop]);
            if (this.parsed == 'Audi'  || this.parsed == 'BMW' ||  this.parsed == 'Volkswagen' || this.parsed == 'Mercedes'  ) {
                if (this.parsed == 'Audi') {
                    this.audi =  obj[prop];
                    console.log('it is an ' + obj[prop]);
                }
                if (this.parsed == 'BMW') {
                    this.bmw =  obj[prop];
                    console.log('it is an ' + obj[prop]);
                }
                if (this.parsed == 'Volkswagen') {
                    this.volkswagen =  obj[prop];
                    console.log('it is an ' + obj[prop]);
                }
                if (this.parsed == 'Mercedes') {
                    this.mercedes =  obj[prop];
                    console.log('it is an ' + obj[prop]);
                }
           }
             else console.log('it´s another car')
        }
    }


    @Method()
    async getHsn() {
        return this.hsn;
    }

    componentWillLoad() {
        return (this.loadWS(this.apiPath)
        );
    }


    loadWS(url: RequestInfo) {
        return fetch(url)
            .then((response: Response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                this.wsresult = response;
                this.checkLogo(response);
                console.log('this parsed contains ' + this.parsed);

            });
    }
```

The following should be refactored through the component property; the title should be different according to the page the user is on / stepped on. The title should be set as a property

```
render() {
    let title;
    if (this.page === 1) {
        title = 'Ihr Fahrzeughersteller';
    } else if (this.page === 2) {
        title = 'Modell';
    } else if (this.page === 3) {
        title = 'Kraftstoff';
    } else if (this.page === 4) {
        title = 'Fahrzeugkategorie';
    } else if (this.page === 5) {
        title = 'Leistung';
    } else if (this.page === 6) {
        title = 'Bitte wählen Sie Ihr Fahrzeug';
    }
```

This should be refactored aswell, meaning that the properties should be passed instead of the page number

```
 if (this.page === 5) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <vhv-icon class='backbutton' onClick={() => this.pageBack()}
                              icon={Icon.Left}/>
                    <h1>{title}</h1>

                    <div class='listwrapper'>
                        {
                            this.wsresult.sort((a: any, b: any) => a.horsePowerFrom - b.horsePowerFrom).map(((element: any) =>
                                    <div class='listelement' onClick={() => this.nextStep(element.key)}>
                                        {element.horsePowerFrom}-{element.horsePowerTo} PS
                                        <vhv-icon size={25} icon={Icon.Right}/>
                                    </div>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>

            );
        } else if (this.page === 6) {
            return (
                <div>
                   {/* <vhv-icon class='backbutton' onClick={() => this.pageBack()}
                              icon={Icon.Left}/>*/}
                    <h1>{title}</h1>
                    <div class='listwrapper'>
                        {
                            this.wsresult.sort((a: any, b: any) => a.horsePowerFrom - b.horsePowerFrom).map(((element: any) =>
                                    <div class='listelement'
                                         onClick={() => this.setTsnHsn(element.tsn, element.hsn, element.brand, element.modelDetailed)}>
                                        {element.modelComplete} HSN: {element.hsn} TSN: {element.tsn}
                                        <vhv-icon size={25} icon={Icon.Right}/>
                                    </div>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        } else if (this.page === 7) {
            return (
                <div class='fertig'>
                    <div class='fertigwrapper'>
                        <img src='https://www.xxx.de/tarifrechner/auto/bmw@2x.fdc06cc429d06c8c96fc.png'/>
                        {this.selectedcar}
                    </div>
                    <vhv-button onClick={() => this.reset()} icon={Icon.Check}>Neue Suche</vhv-button>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (

                <div>
                     <h1>{title}</h1>
                    <div class="vhv-cs-front">
                        <vhv-search  placeholder="Hersteller suchen..."></vhv-search>
                    </div>
                    <div class='list_wrapper'>
                        <div class='listwrapper top'>
                            <div class='listelement top'>
                                <p>Häufig gewählte Hersteller</p>
                            </div>

                            {this.wsresult.slice(0, 7).sort((a: any, b: any) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value)).map(((element: any) =>
                                        <div class='listelement' onClick={() => this.nextStep(element.key)}>
                                            {this.audi === element.value &&
                                             <img hidden={this.page !== 1} src='/assets/logos/audi.png' />}
                                            {this.bmw === element.value &&
                                            <img hidden={this.page !== 1} src='/assets/logos/bmw.png' />}
                                            {this.mercedes === element.value &&
                                            <img hidden={this.page !== 1} src='/assets/logos/mercedes.png' />}
                                            {this.volkswagen === element.value &&
                                            <img hidden={this.page !== 1} src='/assets/logos/volkswagen-vw.png' />}
                                             <vhv-icon size={25} icon={Icon.Right}/>
                                            {element.value}
                                        </div>
                                ))
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div class='listwrapper'>
                            <div class='listelement top'>
                                <p>Alle Hersteller</p>
                            </div>
                            {
                                this.wsresult.sort((a: any, b: any) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value)).map(((element: any) =>
                                        <div class='listelement' onClick={() => this.nextStep(element.key)}>
                                            {this.audi === element.value &&
                                            <img hidden={this.page !== 1} src='/assets/logos/audi.png' />}
                                            {this.bmw === element.value &&
                                            <img hidden={this.page !== 1} src='/assets/logos/bmw.png' />}
                                            {this.mercedes === element.value &&
                                            <img hidden={this.page !== 1} src='/assets/logos/mercedes.png' />}
                                            {this.volkswagen === element.value &&
                                            <img hidden={this.page !== 1} src='/assets/logos/volkswagen-vw.png' />}
                                            <vhv-icon size={25} icon={Icon.Right}/>
                                            {element.value}
                                        </div>
                                ))
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    nextStep(value: string) {
        if (this.page === 1) {
            //this.loadWS(this.actUrl + ? this.key + value) .then(
            // this.actUrl = this.actUrl + this.key
            //  this.key <- aus konstanten
            //)
            this.loadWS(this.apiPath + '?brand=' + value).then(() => {
                this.brand = value;
                this.page = 2;
            });
        } else if (this.page === 2) {
            this.loadWS(this.apiPath + '?brand=' + this.brand + '&model=' + value).then(() => {
                this.model = value;
                this.page = 3;
            });
        } else if (this.page === 3) {
            this.loadWS(this.apiPath + '?brand=' + this.brand + '&model=' + this.model + '&fuel=' + value).then(() => {
                this.fuel = value;
                this.page = 4;
            });
        } else if (this.page === 4) {
            this.loadWS(
                this.apiPath + '?brand=' + this.brand + '&model=' + this.model + '&fuel=' + this.fuel + '&variant=' + value).then(() => {
                this.variant = value;
                this.page = 5;
            });
        } else if (this.page === 5) {
            const url = `${this.apiPath}?brand=${this.brand}&model=${this.model}&fuel=${this.fuel}&variant=${this.variant}&power=${value}`;
            this.loadWS(url).then(() => {
                this.power = value;
                this.page = 6;
            });
        }
    }


 The following are the two methods that should be refactored. They should take properties as values and pass them so that the url is set according to the step that the user is in, same for the following method 



  pageBack() {
        this.page--;
        if (this.page === 1) {
            return this.componentWillLoad();
        } else if (this.page === 2) {
            return this.loadWS(this.apiPath + '?brand=' + this.brand);
        } else if (this.page === 3) {
            return this.loadWS(this.apiPath + '?brand=' + this.brand + '&model=' + this.model);
        } else if (this.page === 4) {
            return this.loadWS(this.apiPath + '?brand=' + this.brand + '&model=' + this.model + '&fuel=' + this.fuel);
        } else if (this.page === 5) {
            return this.loadWS(`${this.apiPath}?brand=${this.brand}&model=${this.model}&fuel=${this.fuel}&variant=${this.variant}`);
        }
    }

    setTsnHsn(tsn: string, hsn: number, brand: string, model: string) {
        this.tsn = tsn;
        this.hsn = hsn;
        this.selectedcar = brand + ' ' + model;
        this.page = 7;

        this.carSelected.emit({
            hsn: this.hsn,
            tsn: this.tsn
        });
    }

    reset() {
        this.page = 1;
        this.tsn = null;
        this.hsn = null;
        return this.componentWillLoad();
    }
}
```

I created a Model that contains the different values as arrays so that when ever the user steps through the component, a different value is passed e.g. as a page title, like so:

```
  export interface xxxCarsearchPropertiesModel
        {

            key: ['brand', 'model','fuel','variant','power', 'choose']
            header: ['Ihr Fahrzeughersteller', 'Modell','Kraftstoff','Fahrzeugkategorie','Leistung']
            listTitle: ['Alle Hersteller','Alle Modelle',]
            favoritesTitle: ['Häufig gewählte Hersteller']
            hasSearch: [true, false]
            searchPlaceholder: ['Hersteller suchen …']
        }
```

Intelectually, I understand what needs to be done, but not practically, because I am not sure on how to use Stencil.js Properties and State in combination with Arrays to achieve the desired result (refactoring of the three methods pageBack(), nextStep() and reset(). In the end ,the values of keys, header, listTitle etc. should be set as properties in the component and be visible accordingly.

Any help or hints would be very much appreciated as I definitely didn´t found any solution to it.

Comment: Could you provide codesandbox.io example. it will help to understand and debug the problem.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the Stencil.js documentation? https://stenciljs.com/docs/properties, https://stenciljs.com/docs/state and https://stenciljs.com/docs/reactive-data#handling-arrays-and-objects should cover most of your questions.